# visual studio won't let me use Else

Tags: c#

I am learing c# and was fallowing a tutorial and when i tryed to type an else statement like the tutorial showed, it gave me 6 errors saying things like "expected )", "invalid expression 'else'", and "expected ;". i tryed puting (); at the end of else but it didnt help. here is my code

```
        if (responseFile[resp].IndexOf('+') == 0);
            {
                List<string> responses = responseFile[resp].Replace('+', ' ').Split('/').Reverse().ToList();
                Random r = new Random();
                say(responses[r.Next(responses.Count)]);
            }
            else 
            {
                say(responseFile[resp]);
            }
```

Comment: You have a stray `;` at the end of the first line. That's ending the `if`, so the `else` will be out of place.

Comment: To elaborate on Carcigenicate's comment: `if (...);` is equivalent to `if (...) { }`. Everything that comes after it is _outside_ the `if` block. If you're using Visual Studio, it probably gave you a _"Possible mistaken empty statement"_ warning.

Comment: next time just use the [snippets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-csharp-code-snippets?view=vs-2019). Type `if` followed with tapping TAB twice, etc

Answer (score 2):

The form of an if/else block should look like this:

```
bool condition = true;

if (condition)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The variable is set to true.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("The variable is set to false.");
}
```

You almost have this form, but you need to remove the ; as that only should follow a regular statement such as `int c = 5;` rather than a condition block or any loops (which includes switches, try/catch/finally, for, foreach, while, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You have to quit the ; at the end of the first line, like that:

```
if (responseFile[resp].IndexOf('+') == 0)
            {
                List<string> responses = responseFile[resp].Replace('+', ' ').Split('/').Reverse().ToList();
                Random r = new Random();
                say(responses[r.Next(responses.Count)]);
            }
            else 
            {
                say(responseFile[resp]);
            }
```